# HAProxy Lua script dont print/log host or path in tcp mode

Tags: lua, haproxy

The problem is that when using the **tcp** mode the Lua script dont log/print the host, path and only the ip is getting logged/printed. If i change the mode to **http** it prints/output everything, but i need it in tcp mode. Can someone help me to fix that?

This is how my HAProxy Configuration file look:

```
frontend RTMP
bind 0.0.0.0:1935
mode tcp
use_backend %[lua.choose_backend("d")]

backend a
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    server origin_1 192.168.1.19:1935 check fall 3 rise 2

backend b
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    server origin_1 192.168.1.20:1935 check fall 3 rise 2
```

And this is how my Lua script:

```
function my_hash(txn, salt)

local str = ""
str = "HOST: " .. txn.sf:req_fhdr("host")
str = str .. " PATH: "
str = str .. txn.sf:path()
str = str .. " SRC: "
str = str .. txn.sf:src()

core.log(core.info, str)
   return 'a'
end

core.register_fetches("choose_backend", my_hash)
```

I just want to get the uri and path requested...such simple thing

Comment: It's **not** exactly a simple thing.  You are asking why **HTTP fetches** do not work on a **non-HTTP** front-end.  Is the traffic actually HTTP?  If so, why TCP mode? If not, what protocol is it?  If the client speaks first, it should be possible to *analyze* the incoming request in Lua, but more information about your application is needed.

Comment: TCP mode, becouse its a rtmp server so the client will connect into: rtmp://domain/something via HAProxy, but " something " can be anything so i wanted to know that url path of the request :)

Comment: I just want HA-Proxy to load balance RTMP (TCP) BASED on URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, this was solved by replacing the frontend with listen. And adding "option transparent"

```
listen RTMP
  option transparent
  bind 0.0.0.0:1935
  mode tcp
  use_backend %[lua.choose_backend("d")]enter code here
```